# jquery on change returns <option></option>

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method called that returns a `List<string>`.  The first one returns a list of years and populates a select using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $yearDropDownList.attr('data-request-url'),
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
            $yearDropDownList.append($('<option/>', { value: item, text: item }));
        });
    }
});
```

The second one is populated on the change of the `yearDropDownList`. 
It is hitting the method and it is returning the data, but when I
click on the select, everything is blank.  There are just
`<option></option>`

Here is the on change:

```
$yearDropDownList.on('change', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $makeDropDownList.attr('data-request-url'),
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { year: $yearDropDownList.find(':selected').text() },
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).each(function(index, item) {
               $makeDropDownList.append($(<option/>")).val(index).text(item);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The second part of your question got wrapped up in the bottm part your code snippet,  a bit hard to spot.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  In the body of your post please specify what issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: @KeithBeller, it's there, last line of the first code snippet. The first line of the paragraph got indented so it got included in with the code, I tried to edit the post but it already has one pending edit.

Comment: @enki.dev, sorry didn't see it.  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

```
$makeDropDownList.append($(<option/>")).val(index).text(item);
```

you are creating a blank `option` and not setting the `val` and `text` on it.

change it to do how you are in the first call:-

```
$makeDropDownList.append($('<option/>', { value: index, text: item}));
```

or move the second bracket to the right around option to the end and fix the 1 double quote.

```
$makeDropDownList.append($('<option/>').val(index).text(item));
```

Comment: I tried all these. None work. I did notice it is calling on change method twice, the first time, it is populated with values, the second time it is not.

Comment: The fix for your question is above, but I cant see the double event issue in the code you have shown. Are you adding the same change event more than once? try putting a break point in the change event from the developer console and look at the call stack when it hits for both occurrences. You should be able to track down where its coming from.